# Как поместить картинки в блок

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, ребята. Мне нужно поместить картинки товаров в блок 280x200, так, чтобы блок полностью заполнился и картинки не поменяли свои пропорции, если пропорции мешают, то обрезать, то есть не надо, чтобы картинка растягивалась, а просто обрезалась. Я пытался разными способами, но не получилось.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/obf3eunh/

Answer (score 4):

*1) Устанавливай картинку фоном и задай ей размер **cover**:*

```css
.block {
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0e701b6571349036da776281d23d065a?s=300&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

*2) Вариант с позиционированием:*

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0e701b6571349036da776281d23d065a?s=300&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
</div>
```

Но с этим вариантом морока, так как ты не знаешь по ширине ровнять на всю или по высоте.

Если это идею развивать, то можно с помощью PHP определять размер картинки: картинка больше по ширине или высоте. Если картинка больше по ширине, то устанавливать класс `.imgh`, и этот класс будет устанавливать размер картинке `{width: auto; height: 100%}`, а если больше высота, то ставить `.imgv`, который будет иметь размеры `{width: 100%; height: auto}`.

*Пример:*

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.block > img.imgh {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.block > img.imgv {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<h3>Берём картинку, где ширина больше высоты</h3>

<p>И видим, что по высоте картинка не полная:</p>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/f/f9/Generator_Company.jpg">
</div>

<h3>Для нормального определения, нужно определять в PHP, что больше, ширина или высота</h3>

<p>Если ширина больше, то устанавливаем класс с размерами {width: auto; height: 100%}</p>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/f/f9/Generator_Company.jpg" class="imgh">
</div>
```

---

А вообще, вам мой совет, при добавлении картинки товара, в PHP сделайте, чтобы картинка ужималась и обрезалась до нужного размера. Тогда и подстраивать ничего не нужно будет, и сайт будет меньше загружаться по времени

Comment: Минус мой. Я вот считаю, что если спрашивают о том, как работать с картинкой (в данном случае, картинкой товара), то такой совет бесполезен. В продакшене интернет-магазинов это в 95% случае не применимо.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, а в продакшене соц. сетей и прочих сайтов только это и используют. С картинками мороки много. Ну если хотите, сейчас добавлю картинкой

Comment: такой ответ мне уже нравится больше ) а почему это с картинками много мороки?

Comment: мой случай интернет магазин и я не понимаю, как первый вариант использовать с background-image: url, потому-что картинка берется с бд с помощью php

Comment: @Dem, в `style` можно вставлять. Я на своём сайте так и сделал. Ну или можете определять в PHP, что у картинки больше, ширина или высота. Дальше применяете специальный класс, который будет по высоте или ширине ровнять на всю.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, ну откуда ты знаешь по какому критерию ровнять: по ширине или длине? )

Comment: @Yuri *по ширине или длине?* — а в чем их разница в 2д-пространстве? :D

Comment: ну и как например сделать в этом файле https://yadi.sk/d/g2gx2jbJ3FYg4i. строки кода блока с картинкой с 128 по 149. я уже несколько дней бьюсь

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, ну, когда ты ровняешь картинку, то пишешь ширине *100%*, а высоте *auto*. А если Высота меньше чем ширина, то блок будет не полностью заполнен

Comment: @Dem, вы про что? Как определить что больше: ширина или высота?

Comment: больше ширина, ширина 280px, высота 200px

Comment: @Dem, нет, ну что вы спрашивали?

Comment: в смысле? то, есть надо поменять высота 100%, а ширина auto?

Comment: @Dem, я привёл пример проблемы и её решение

Comment: object-fit/object-position почитайте

Comment: вроде получилось, но вроде только почему-то не уменьшается((. а так полностью заполнилось